# Finding volume of the solid

Tags: calculus

The region bounded by the curve $y=\sqrt{x}$ , the $x$-axis and the line $x=4$ is revolved about $y$-axis to generate a solid. Find the volume of solid.

I found $32\pi/5$ ? But answer is wrong. Where did I wrong?

$$\text{Volume}_{\space y} = \pi \int_0^2 [A(y)]^2dy = \pi \int_0^2 y^4dy$$

Answer (score 1):

What you calculated is the solid generated by the area *above* the curve.

So the correct answer should be
$$
\pi\cdot 4^2\cdot 2-I
$$
where $I$ is what you found.

Comment: Really Thanks really for your answer. I have two questions : a-) Without drawing, is it possible to solve all problems in integral? ( Do we need to draw) b-) There exists some methods like Washer Method, Disk Method etc. Any method is enough for all volumes of the solids? I don't know which method I should use actually